# Line touching a sphere.

Tags: geometry

I am having 2 points let us say $P(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $Q(x_2+d_1*t,y_2+d_2t,z_2+d_3*t)$ , here I know the values of $x_1,y_1,z_1$ and $x_2,y_2, z_2$. And I need to know the value of $t$, given that the line joining these two points is just touching the sphere with center at $(c_x,c_y,c_z)$ and radius $r$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ,Sorry i am new to this site , sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the coordinates of tangency of an external point to a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805584/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-tangency-of-an-external-point-to-a-sphere)

Comment: In general there is no guarantee that a value $t$ can be adduced that makes the line $P$ tangent to a specified sphere of fixed radius $r$.  However for any fixed $t$ there will be a radius $r$ so the sphere centered at a given point $(c_x,c_y,c_z)$ not on $PQ$ of that radius is tangent to that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line from $\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix}\right]$ to $\left[\begin{matrix}x_2+t \\ y_2+t \\ z_2+t \end{matrix}\right]$.
The center of the sphere is at $\left[\begin{matrix}x_c \\ y_c \\ z_c \end{matrix} \right]$, and radius $r$. For the line to "just touch" the sphere, the minimum distance between the line and the sphere must be exactly $r$.

As e.g. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) tells us, the minimum distance between a point $\vec{p}$ and a line that passes through points $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, is
$$d = \frac{\left\lVert (\vec{b} - \vec{a}) \times (\vec{a} - \vec{p}) \right\rVert}{\left\lVert \vec{b} - \vec{a} \right\rVert} = \frac{\left\lVert (\vec{p} - \vec{a}) \times (\vec{p} - \vec{b}) \right\rVert}{\left\lVert \vec{b} - \vec{a} \right\rVert}$$
where vector norm $\left\lVert\vec{c}\right\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{c} \cdot \vec{c}}$, $\cdot$ denoting vector dot product, and $\times$ denoting vector cross product. (You can pick either right side; the result will be the same either way.)

In many cases, it is easier to square both sides; i.e. use e.g.
$$d^2 = \frac{\left( (\vec{b} - \vec{a}) \times (\vec{a} - \vec{p}) \right) \cdot \left( (\vec{b} - \vec{a}) \times (\vec{a} - \vec{p}) \right)}{\left( \vec{b} - \vec{a} \right)\cdot\left(\vec{b} - \vec{a}\right)}$$
Squaring both sides is allowed, because both sides are nonnegative (zero or positive).

What you need to do, is to set $d = r$, $\vec{a} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ]$, $\vec{b} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 + t \\ y_2 + t \\ z_2 + t \end{matrix} \right ]$, $\vec{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_c \\ y_c \\ z_c \end{matrix} \right ]$, and solve for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Simplify the equation by multiplying both sides by the denominator, then moving everything to the left side.  This way, you get a quadratic polynomial in $t$,
$$C_2 t^2 + C_1 t + C_0 = 0$$
where $C_0$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ have lots of terms; the solutions are of course
$$t = \frac{-C_1}{2 C_2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{C_1^2 - 4 C_2 C_0}}{2 C_2}$$

Edited to add: The exact terms are
$$\begin{aligned}
C_2 = &\; (x_c - x_1 - y_c + y_1)^2 \\
    + &\; (x_c - x_1 - z_c + z_1)^2 \\
    + &\; (y_c - y_1 - z_c + z_1)^2 - 3 r^2 \\
C_1 = &\; 2 r^2 (x_1 - x_2 + y_1 - y_2 + z_1 - z_2) \\
    + &\; 2 (y_2 + z_2) (x_c - x_1)^2 \\
    + &\; 2 (x_2 + z_2) (y_c - y_1)^2 \\
    + &\; 2 (x_2 + y_2) (z_c - z_1)^2 \\
    + &\; 2 x_c (z_1 + y_1) (x_1 + x_2 - x_c) \\
    + &\; 2 y_c (z_1 + x_1) (y_1 + y_2 - y_c) \\
    + &\; 2 z_c (y_1 + x_1) (z_1 + z_2 - z_c) \\
    - &\; 2 y_1 (z_c + x_c) (y_1 - y_2 - y_c) \\
    - &\; 2 z_1 (x_c + y_c) (z_1 - z_2 - z_c) \\
    - &\; 2 x_1 (y_c + z_c) (x_1 - x_2 - x_c) \\
    - &\; 2 (x_1 y_1 + x_c y_c) (x_2 + y_2) \\
    - &\; 2 (x_1 z_1 + x_c z_c) (x_2 + z_2) \\
    - &\; 2 (y_1 z_1 + y_c z_c) (y_2 + z_2) \\
C_0 = &\; (x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1)^2 + (x_1 z_2 - x_2 z_1)^2 \\
    + &\; (y_1 z_2 - y_2 z_1)^2 + (x_1 y_c - x_c y_1)^2 \\
    + &\; (x_1 z_c - x_c z_1)^2 + (y_1 z_c - y_c z_1)^2 \\
    + &\; (x_2 y_c - x_c y_2)^2 + (x_2 z_c - x_c z_2)^2 \\
    + &\; (y_2 z_c - y_c z_2)^2 \\
    + &\; 2 x_1 (y_2 y_c + z_2 z_c) (x_c - x_1) \\
    + &\; 2 x_2 (y_1 y_c + z_1 z_c) (x_1 - x_2) \\
    + &\; 2 x_c (y_1 y_2 + z_1 z_2) (x_2 - x_c) \\
    + &\; 2 y_1 (x_2 x_c + z_2 z_c) (y_c - y_1) \\
    + &\; 2 y_2 (x_1 x_c + z_1 z_c) (y_1 - y_2) \\
    + &\; 2 y_c (x_1 x_2 + z_1 z_2) (y_2 - y_c) \\
    + &\; 2 z_1 (x_2 x_c + y_2 y_c) (z_c - z_1) \\
    + &\; 2 z_2 (x_1 x_c + y_1 y_c) (z_1 - z_2) \\
    + &\; 2 z_c (x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2) (z_2 - z_c) \\
    - &\; r^2 ( (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 + (z_2 - z_1)^2 ) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @amd These seem to be two different problems. The problem asked here is to find the intersections of a line with the cone with vertex $P$ subtended by the sphere. It's a quadratic problem with zero, one, or two solutions.