# Find the vector point equation

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I have a point A(x,y,z) at time (t)=0 where A moves in a straight line with constant velocity with direction vector D(dx,dy,dz) as a function of time(t) given by 
A(t)=A(0)+(D.t).I could not figure out what this mean?...
I have calculated the Points of A at time t  as
 ( x+(dx * t) , y+(dy * t) , z+(dz * t) ) but this gives me wrong answers .
Can any one help me derieve the equation for points of A at time t.
Thanks in advance.

Actually this is for programming.I have follwed the steps to get to solution as stated in [math.stackexchange.com/a/2805278/567587] . I have to frame the point s functions correctly so that i can get the correct results. I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: It looks correct to me ... What is the result you obtained and what is the correct answer? Do you have the equations as a function of time?

Comment: Actually this is for programming.I have follwed the steps to get to solution as stated in [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2805278/567587]  . I have to frame the point s functions correctly so that i can get the correct results. I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Your generic parametric equation is correct. If you want someone to help you figure out why this doesn’t produce the correct result, you’ll need to provide a specific example of this.

Comment: Note that $t$ is a parameter that changes the direction of the line, in the linked answer. I'll see if I can simplify the terms enough to show in the answer itself.

Comment: That would help me in a better way @Nominal Animal

Comment: Actually it is correct for the example test case given in question but it produces wrong answer when the code is submitted.  Here is the problem question 
 https://www.codechef.com/JUNE18B/problems/VSN  @amd

Comment: @jarvis: The question is not public, so can't help you there. However, I do suspect the actual problem differs in a fundamental way from both this and the other question; the problem is probably to find the smallest (shortest) change in one point so that a line through that and another point no longer intersects a ball.

Comment: I could not understand that Q(t)=Q(0)+d.t as there is a Q initial point and also  whether i have to do like Qx(t)=Qx(0)+(dx*t)?..can you please clarify my doubt. @Nominal Animal

Comment: And how to make this question public? I am new to this site..

Comment: I meant, the codechef.com page you refer to is not public, so I (and others reading this question) cannot read that link.

Comment: You can look at the question but you should login to solve it in codechef.com .

Comment: Even better, instead of linking to another site and forcing people who want to help you to have to figure out how to access it, include **all** of the relevant information in your question.